# Getting a blank page in place of UI for vue 3 + laravel 8 to do list app

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3

I am getting a blank page for the vue3 app in laravel8. It was working separately with vue3 cli. Laravel8 and vue3 are correctly installed as I have checked their versions

Below are the source codes for relevant files:
**welcome.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />

    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="app">
                <vue-app />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue';
    
const app = createApp({});
app.component('vue-app', App)
    .mount('#app');
    
require('./bootstrap');
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <Header @toggle-add-task="toggleAddTask" title='Task Tracker' :showAddTask="showAddTask" />
        <div v-show="showAddTask">
            <AddTask @addTask="addTask" />
        </div>
        <Tasks @toggle-reminder="toggleReminder" @delete-task="deleteTask" :tasks="tasks" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header'
import Tasks from './components/Tasks'
import AddTask from './components/AddTask'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
   Header,
   AddTask,
   Tasks
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      showAddTask: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTask(id) {
      if(confirm('Are you sure'))
      this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((task) => id!==task.id)

    },
    toggleReminder(id)
    {
      this.tasks = this.tasks.map((task) => id===task.id ? {...task, reminder: !task.reminder}:task)
    },
    addTask(task)
    {
      this.tasks = [...this.tasks, task];
    },
    toggleAddTask()
    {
      this.showAddTask = !this.showAddTask;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.tasks = [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'doctors Appointment',
        day: 'March 1st at 2:30pm',
        reminder: true,
      },
       {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Meeting Appointment',
        day: 'March 1st at 2:30pm',
        reminder: false,
      },
       {
        id: 3,
        text: 'School Appointment',
        day: 'March 1st at 2:30pm',
        reminder: true,
      },
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
        
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .vue()
       .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css');
```

`npm run dev` and `npm run watch` work fine with no errors or warnings

**I have also attached the folder structure in laravel from vscode**
[image: folder structure]

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need  `<vue-app />` component as your app is mounted on the element with the ID `app`. check you browser console to see exactly what is wrong.